# Trying to import data from my university parking api in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to acquire live parking information from an API which is provided by my university. I am able to get data when I run the java code. But when I put this code in the android studio, it is giving me an exception.
This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.parth.p4">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Check"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my file where I am running the java code:

```
package com.example.parth.p4;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Check extends AppCompatActivity {


    public TextView t;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_check);

        try {
            chk();
        }catch (Exception  e)
        {
           t.setText("Error");
        }


    }
    private static Document loadTestDocument(String url) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        return factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new URL(url).openStream());
    }
    public void chk() throws Exception {
        t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
       String carPoolSpacesAvailable;
        Document doc = loadTestDocument("https://api.uow.edu.au/parking/data/?format=xml");



        NodeList nodes1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("parks");



        carPoolSpacesAvailable = nodes1.item(6).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

         t.setText(carPoolSpacesAvailable);

    }
}
```

This is my xml file where I am trying to show the data in a textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Check">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="331dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The output which I am getting is the error message which I have put in the catch block in the oncreate() method.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not making a network call on the MAIN UI Thread.

Try to call the chk() from background thread.

```
 TextView t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    new DownloadFilesTask().execute();



}
// doInBackground is called from the background thread while the onPostExecute is called on the Main Thread.

private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String carPoolSpacesAvailable = null;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
         try {
        Document
            doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new URL("https://api.uow.edu.au/parking/data/?format=xml").openStream());
             NodeList nodes1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("parks");

             carPoolSpacesAvailable = nodes1.item(6).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

         } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return carPoolSpacesAvailable;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if(s!=null){
            t.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Try this in your second activity.

Comment: how do can i do that

Comment: Try to use Asynk task. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: Can you share the modified code if its possible in the answer which you have provided?because i am new to android

Comment: Please check the answer now , have edited it with a code sample.

Comment: It is giving me this error in logcat:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method check(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'

Comment: This is because os a onClick method  that you have added to the button. remove it if you are not using it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178286/discussion-between-parth-and-kaveri).

Comment: But as you said earlier, you could retain this method in your first activity , in the method  just intent it to second activity , and add the above code in the second activity, since you wanted to show it in the second page.

Comment: Great to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code by writing:

```
    try {
        chk();
    }catch (Exception  e)
    {
       Log.e("Error : ", "" + e.getMessage());
       t.setText("Error");
    }
```

After this run it, check the Logat in Error section and post a screenshot of the exception here.